# How to stretch my dropdown menu horizontally & highlight chosen menu item?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I'm using the dropdown from
http://www.lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/

My menu has Home|About|Register|Login
I would like the menu to look like

Home|About|Register|Login<-----------------stretch till end ----------------->

What i'm doing now is create an extra li and add "&nbsp" to it. The code is as below

```
<div id="mymenu">
<ul class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal">
<li class="first"><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/reg">Register</a></li>
<li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
<li class="last"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Also how do i highlight choosen menu item like for example if i click home the menu home should be highlighted.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your desired and actual results are. A jsFiddle or other demo would be helpful.

Comment: As MrCode said, your code is needed to help you there. But still, to highlight a menu item when clicked, you'll need extra technology there (like PHP or Javascript) to tell your code this specific item should be highlighted. And the &nbsp; trick is not a good idea, it won't display the same result on all browser ...

Comment: could use li:last-child or something to that effect and ad a margin-left to that rather than your &nbsp;